# Ruby - Fork throws Errno::EPIPE

Tags: ruby, resque

What are the circumstances in which a `fork do` call would throw `Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe`? I'm using Resque on an AWS instance and bizarrely, while Resque runs fine on a staging server, it is constantly throwing these broken pipe errors when it tries to have a worker fork a child process on a production server even though they are using the same AMI. I've put in enough logging statements to identify that the error is thrown when Resque attempts to fork:

```rb
@child = fork do
          unregister_signal_handlers if term_child
          perform(job, &block)
          exit! unless run_at_exit_hooks
        end
```

So the error comes from that top line (https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L909). I'm not clear though why a `fork` call would throw a `Errno:EPIPE`. The server has plenty of memory, CPU, and hard drive to spare.

Comment: Seems like this would be hard for someone here to reproduce. Do you have full backtrace errors? Maybe also see https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/1628

Comment: I do, but the backtrace isn't helpful beyond pointing to the `fork` line that I linked above. I know that no one can replicate my application, so my question is more "how can a `fork` command generate a `Broken pipe`?